# How to disable broadcast in a Databricks notebook?

Tags: pyspark, databricks

When I run a query in Databricks/PySpark I get the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not execute broadcast in 300 secs. You can increase the timeout for broadcasts via spark.sql.broadcastTimeout or disable broadcast join by setting spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold to -1
```

How do I do this programmatically (Python) in a Databricks notebook? I have tried the below:

```
>>> spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold(-1)

result:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'autoBroadcastJoinThreshold'


>>> spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold = -1

result:
AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'autoBroadcastJoinThreshold'
```

Maybe `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` is a property key and this property can somehow be set to -1, but I haven't yet found any documentation that describes how to accomplish this using Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cluster configuration page for the Spark settings is where this can be specified.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used this in databricks before my join command and it worked:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout" ,"-1")
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for answering but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the issue? Check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in cluster configuration as in the accepted answer.

Also, you can set in in a notebook:

[image: broadcast_threshold_limit]